# updating image in window using loop

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import time


def put_pixel(row, col):
    pixels[row, col] = [255, 255, 255]


width = 20
height = 10


pixels = np.full((height, width, 3), 0, dtype=np.uint8)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.configure(background='grey')

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("maze.png"))

panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side = "top")

b = tk.Button(root, text="Sure!")
b.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

for i in range(1, width-2, 2):
    put_pixel(5, i)
    time.sleep(2)

    img = Image.fromarray(pixels, 'RGB')
    panel.configure(image=img)
    panel.image = img

root.mainloop()
```

The script just adds white pixels on a black image. But I want it to be animated to see the adding of every pixel step by step. So I tried to update an image in a label after every single pixel being added. But I got an error

> _tkinter.TclError: image "" doesn't exist

If I don't use loop and just put an image into a label it works fine. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the PIL.Image into a tkinter.PhotoImage:

```
img = Image.fromarray(pixels, 'RGB')
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
panel.configure(image=tkimg)
panel.image = img
```

tkinter.Label will only accept this type, not PIL images.